# Can't boot from USB on MacBook Pro Retina

Tags: macos, boot, dd

I downloaded the latest i386 netinst iso for Debian Jessie and have followed these instructions: http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-mac-osx

However, when I press alt/option when starting the Mac, the USB drive doesn't appear as an option to boot to.

Comment: Did you press the `opt` button from boot ? [just asking in case you only pressed it once]